# Diagnosing I/O Bandwidth Performance in SQL Anywhere

Tags: performance, sqlanywhere

While diagnosing performance issues with vendor software that runs off of SQL Anywhere (9.0.2), I stumbled upon some interesting data in regards to I/O Bandwidth. According to the 9.0.2 manual, the database property "CurrIO" shows "The current number of file I/Os that were issued by the server but have not yet completed.". However, it's unclear what this number should be, given a hardware configuration and/or database utilization.

After a bit of searching, I found that the SQL Anywhere 10.0.0 manual does go into this setting in a bit more detail in their chapter on performance:

> To detect whether I/O
>   bandwidth is a limiting factor, check
>   the CurrIO database statistic. If this
>   statistic is not present on the graph,
>   click the Add Statistics button and
>   select CurrIO. Look for the largest
>   sustained number for this statistic.
>   For example, look for a high plateau
>   on the graph; the wider it is, the
>   more significant the impact. If the
>   graph has sustained values equal to,
>   or greater than 3 + the number of
>   physical disks used by database
>   server, it may indicate that the disk
>   system cannot keep up with the level
>   of database server activity.

Is this saying that, for example, if I have 5 disks in the server, this number should ideally be below 8? Is the meaning behind this value the same for version 9.0.2 as 10.0.0? The reason I find this hard to believe is the results of the following command are a bit off in my particular case:

```
SELECT db_property ( 'CurrIO' ), db_property ( 'MaxIO' )
```

The above command returns over **900** for the CurrIO and **1150** for the MaxIO. I have been monitoring this number for a few hours and the average is approximately ***950*** (Thanks to the Foxhound monitor from RisingRoad). These readings have been taken under normal database load.

Is my I/O bandwidth truly as inadequate as it looks, or am I misinterpreting these numbers?

Here is the current server configuration:

OS: Windows Server 2003 R2 32-bit

Database Version: SQL Anywhere (Adaptive Server Anywhere) 9.0.2.3381

CPU: 4x Intel Xeon Dual Core 3.00GHz

RAM: 26GB (22GB Allocated to SQL Anywhere cache)

HDD (C:/): OS + Temporary File Location

> RAID 1
>
> 2x 36GB SCSI-320 (15k RPM)

HDD (D:/): DB File Location

> RAID 5
>
> 4x 73GB SCSI-320 (15k RPM)

HDD (E:/): OS Pagefile + Log File Location (There is no Mirror Log)

> RAID 5
>
> 4x 73GB SCSI-320 (15k RPM)

Notes: The RAID1 and first RAID5 (D:/) are on the same RAID controller. We were planning on upgrading both RAID5 with 146GB (15k RPM) drives in RAID10. Would that change help our apparent I/O Bandwidth issue?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with RAIDs the traditional Disk counters in perfmon may give back misleading results. They will show cache I/O rather than disk I/O. So make sure you also look at the `% Idle Time` counter. This will probably the most accurate result, but it will be inverted (lower percentage equals busier disks)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it averages around 20%, so perhaps disk I/O is not an issue.

Comment: If the value you are reading is 20%, that means it's only idle 20% of the time. Meaning 80% of the time it's writing. You are getting very close to having I/O problems.

Comment: My mistake- I actually did the "conversion" when I posted. The graph read around 80% idle, so I/O load was about 20%. That being said, I think the only way to be sure would be to get the information from the RAID controller itself.

Answer (score 1):

The CurrIO statistic is not SMP safe in SA. You'd be better to look at the "PhysicalDisk" counters provided by Windows perfmon. In particular: "Current Disk Queue Length", "Avg. Disk Queue Length", "Avg Disk Write Queue Length" and "Avg. Disk Read Queue Length".

I'm not sure where the "3+#disks" value came from. If you are expecting lots of IO to be done on a drive, it is very reasonable to have several IOs outstanding on that drive.

Comment: I also thought the "3 + # disks" was a little strange- Perfmon doesn't show anything outrageous, so the performance issues may not be due to disk I/O.

Should "CurrRead" and "CurrWrite" be SMP safe? Looks to be around 100/s average, with spikes just over 1,000/s.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see how much I/O is being performed by the database is by looking at the cache statistics. If the database is reading from cache, it isn't doing as much disk I/O. The two db properties that can be viewed are "CacheRead" and "CacheHits", like so:

```
SELECT db_property ( 'CacheRead' ), db_property ( 'CacheHits' )
```

The SQL Anywhere 10.0.0 manual recommends at least a 70% cache hit percentage. If it's below that, you may need to allocate more cache to the server. You can get the percentage directly like this:

```
SELECT STRING(((db_property ( 'CacheHits' ) / db_property ( 'CacheRead' )) * 100), '%')
```

In my particular case, when the database had a 22GB cache, the hit percentage was about 58%. After setting the cache to 55GB, the hit percentage went up to 97%. Although the "CurrIO" and "MaxIO" property exact numbers may be incorrect, the relative drop was drastic after this change as well.